# silverlight exit call a Web service

Tags: silverlight, wcf

I want to send data to the server when you close the application

```
public App()
        {
            this.Startup += this.Application_Startup;
            this.Exit += this.Application_Exit;
            this.UnhandledException += this.Application_UnhandledException;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

private void Application_Exit(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           ClientReverse.UserExitGameAsync((Guid)Login);
        }
```

Server:

```
public void UserExitGame(Guid UserGuid)
        {
            Games.Games.ExitUserGames(UserGuid);
        }
```

but the server side is not satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

It is already too late when you reach the ApplicationExit event.

I have seen Javascript that keeps on a webpage until confirmed (Stack Overflow does it a lot). You might want to modify a version of that Javascript that sends a message back to the Silverlight app before it allows page closing.

Calling Silverlight methods from JS is easy (you can simply expose SL methods to JS with the [`[Scriptable]`](http://weblogs.asp.net/mschwarz/archive/2007/06/01/call-scribtable-methods-from-javascript-with-silverlight.aspx) attribute).

Comment: since silverlight is calling the WCF, why not just call the onbeforunload in the HTML and call with ajax the WCF and not over silverlight?

Comment: @Rumplin: That would also be valid, but I have seen a lot of stories about `onbeforeunload` not working on all browsers properly. Opera apparently does not fire it at all.

Comment: Well ok, didn't know that because I work mainly in closed enviroments (intranet) with IE and Silverlight. Thanks for the tip.